# Performance of data annotation validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I am using data annotations for validating imported data in the back-end. It seems a bad idea while most people use it to validate fields of front-end (e.g: login form or application form). However, it is an amazing idea for my project. Instead of using a huge bunch of if-else statements, now my code is much easier to read and understand.

Before I know about data annotations, for every single model, I had to create its own validation class, which contains a bunch of if-else statements as I said. It caused a lot of confusions in understanding the logic of the validation.

Now, with data annotations, I just need to use one single method to validate the models.

```
    public virtual string ValidateByAnnotations(ImportModel model)
    {
        string errorMessage = "";
        //errorCount = 0;

        var validationContext = new ValidationContext(model, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
        var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();

        var isValid = System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Validator.TryValidateObject(model, validationContext, validationResults, true);

        if (!isValid)
        {
            foreach (ValidationResult message in validationResults)
            {
                if (errorMessage.Contains(message.ToString())) { continue; }
                if (errorCount < maxErrorAllowed)
                {
                    errorCount++;
                    errorMessage += errorMessage.Length > 0 ? " " + message.ErrorMessage : message.ErrorMessage;
                }
                else { return errorMessage; }
            }
        }

        return errorMessage;
    }
```

However, this is just a tip of the iceberg. I confront with another problem which is the performance of the validations. Data annotations help me and my colleagues a lot in understanding the validation, but the new validations process much slower than the old validations. Is there any possible way to keep data annotations in my project and enhance the performance of validations?

Comment: What in the world are you trying to do here? - this is all handled correctly out of the box in mvc. And you get both client and server side validation.

Comment: @StephenMuecke No matter what world I am in now, do you think that validation by data annotations is much slower than a bunch of if-else statements in case of thousands or millions of models?

Comment: No. Definitely not. Its probably faster.

Comment: @StephenMuecke you may be wrong, I have tested with 20000 records, if-else statements just need to check the model's properties line-by-line, it is straightforward. On the other hand, the `Validator.TryValidateObject()` has to create attribute classes and validate the property values. After that, it has to look back the ValidationResult list again to get the error messages.

Comment: Sorry, but this is nonsense. There is no way in the world you are going to have a user editing 20,000 records in a view. And all you need to do is add the attributes to your model properties - e.g. `[Required]`, `[StringLength]` etc etc, and you get client and server side validation out of the box

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry if my question makes you confusing. I am not talking about the MVC structure, I just ask about the validation itself. It means that you can use the validations to validate data for anything, e.g: mine is 20000 lines of a spreadsheet file, my project is to read each line in the spreadsheet, validate each column of the line and generate error messages if any. That's the reason why I am saying that the data annotation validation is slower than the if-else statement in my case.